# Vote count in favorites overflows

Tags: bug, favorites-tab

The vote counts in my favorites section are getting out of place.

[image]

It appears that if the vote count is less than -99, it will overflow and look ugly. (this bug does not happen with questions over 999 votes; it just uses a "kvotes" unit instead.)

I'm using Windows 7, in IE9 (it's terrible, I'm being forced to use the evil browser because this computer doesn't have any other and I can't download stuff `:P`)

Comment: -1 for not enough eeeeeeees in eeeeeeeeeeeeeek.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Please refrain from 'e' inflation - large amounts of 'e's should only be reserved for *truly* earth-shattering scenarios. :P

Comment: Which browser, OS? No-repro on Chrome 28.0.1500.95 m, Firefox 22.0  Windows XP

Comment: @hims056 IE9, win7. (it feels so terrible to be using IE :( I've never wanted to see a Chrome window so much `:P`)

Comment: No repro on IE 9, Windows 7 for zoom varying from 33% to 400%

Comment: @hjpotter92 Hmm, that's odd. I shall investigate more.

Comment: Very strange, nothing seems to be wrong... I'm using IE9 Standards Mode and 100% zoom, so I don't know what could possibly be wrong...